# How to parse string to get only desired text?

Tags: selenium

```
storeText ( locator, variableName ) 
${variableName}
```

If variableName contains value as 'Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300'.
I need to parse this string and store a value 145300 in another variable.
How is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Command: storeEval
Target : '${variableName}'.split(' ').last()
Value  : result
```

Comment: @ Aleh Douhi : Thank U very much. How Can i write the last word in the new separate file ?

Comment: @JackieJames by file you mean another Test Case in Test Suite in Selenium IDE?

Comment: @Jackie James, all stored variables are global for the whole test suite. I.e. you can use any variable anywhere after its declaration.

Comment: But how can i write those variables into new file ?

Comment: @JackieJames just use `${variableName}` or `storedVars.variableName`. Or I misunderstood your question.