# how to create a new file in selenium?

Tags: file-io, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

how to create a new file in selenium ?

```
And also how can i write a data into the newly created file ?
```

How does selenium IDE & Selenium RC differs ?

Comment: can you provide more info about what you want to accomplish!?

Comment: It's just a simple file ( either notepad or wordpad). I just want to create a new file & write data into it. how can i do it ? –

Comment: is there any comands like fopen, fread, fwrite ? or any other different commands ?

Comment: In what language? This isn't a selenium question, this is a programming question related to the language you are coding it in.

Comment: Oh ! Are there no commands to do it in selenium rather than programming ?

Comment: @ Arran: If i want to do it in a perl, how can i do it ? can you please let me know ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming from your [last question and your comments there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011856/how-to-parse-string-to-get-only-desired-text), you want to get some text from a page and save it in a file.

I might be wrong, but I think you can't do that in Selenium IDE and will need the full power of a programming language in Selenium RC (which has been officially deprecated like a year ago) or Selenium WebDriver.

Once you're using one or another in any language you like (currently C#, Java, Ruby, Perl and PHP are supported), you can use the [language's](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java%20write%20into%20file) [standard](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23%20write%20into%20file) [tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ruby%20write%20into%20file) [to write](https://www.google.com/search?q=Perl%20write%20to%20file) into a file.

Comment: It's just a simple file ( either notepad or wordpad). I just want to create a new file & write data into it. how can i do it ? –

Comment: is there any comands like fopen, fread, fwrite ? or any other different commands ?

Comment: You need to check the documentation of whichever language bindings you are using for Selenium. If you can get the data through the Selenium language bindings, you can read and it write to a file using the standard methods for that language.

Comment: @JackieJames No, you can't do it just using Selenium IDE. The list of all Selenium IDE's commands is [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html).

Comment: @ Slanec : Thank u for the information. Then, how can i do it ? May i know the procedure for the same ?

Comment: @JackieJames Export your test case to the language of your choice, open it in your favourite IDE, compile it and run it to be sure the export worked, then implement a simple file write logic (refer to the links in my answer for that).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your file questions, it's not clear whether you are referring to test files, files on the Selenium server, or files on the clients which run the browsers driven by Selenium.

Regarding Selenium IDE vs RC, that question is already answered at:

[What is the difference between Selenium IDE, Server, RC, 2.0, and WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995016/what-is-the-difference-between-selenium-ide-server-rc-2-0-and-webdriver).

Comment: @ Mark : It's just a simple file ( either notepad or wordpad). I just want to create a new file & write data into it. how can i do it ?

Comment: is there any comands like fopen, fread, fwrite ? or any other different commands ?

Comment: You still haven't said where the file is located: Is it on the machine  where the tests are located, the machine where the selenium server is running, or the client machine where the browser is running? It also matters which component you are attempting to read or write the file from.

Comment: I've to create a new file on desktop. I've to write data into it. Is it possible to do in selenium ? if so,what is the command ?

Comment: Is something like File.open(local_filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(doc) } possible ?

Comment: You want a web browser to write to a file on the desktop that you specify? I don't think it can be done, just as Firefox can't write to a file on  your desktop.

Comment: I'm currently executing a testcase in selenium after recording some actions. During this time, some of the values are stored in variables. I need to write these stored variables into separate file.Later appending second set dat for comparison. How can i do it ?